# Handle Scrolling in Android AppbarLayout

Tags: android

I need to handle the scrolling behaviour in my app. I have a screen with Colloapsing toolbar and tablayout viewpager. In this tablayout i have 3 tables.
First tab is content description. Second Tab and Thired Tab contains the List items.
Here the content of description and the list items is small i want to disable the appbar scrolling for each tab. If the content is large or list item is larger have to enable the appbar scrolling. Can any one know how to handle this..